# Show new data and replace the old data in the same position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Get the second data by pressing the button and the list should display in the html page. It should replace the old data with a new data.

Problem:
I cannot make the button to be working in order to display the result on the webpage. Show new data and replace the old data.

What part am I missing?

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fetch-data-from-api-f632fh?

Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  };

  getSecondData() {
    fetch('https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Activities')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ data });
      });
  }

  showAlert() {
    alert("I'm an alert");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getSecondData}>ASDF</button>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data &&
            this.state.data.map(user => <li id={user.id}>{user.id}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Changing your method to `getSecondData = () => { }` should do the trick, so `this.setState` is available.

Comment: The calling context of `this` is not the component class in `onClick` callback. Can also do `onClick={this.getSecondData.bind(this)}`

Comment: To add on to all of the (correct) answers above: you can also bind your method in the constructor `this.getSecondData = this.getSecondData.bind(this)`. This is what the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) recommend for performance reasons. But for a smaller project, you're unlikely to notice any difference.

Comment: Move to function components to get rid of `this` issues .

Comment: If you can provide a sample in stackblitz it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing a couple of things.

First of all, you should never setState like that. Instead, always use prevState. Like this:
this.setState(prevState => ({
...prevState,
data
}));
Second, you either need to bind the function you are creating in the constructor like this: this.getSecondData = this.getSecondData.bind(this)
You read more about that here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Or better solution is to just use arrow functions.

The correct working solution can be found here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fetch-data-from-api-znjdf6